# calling a mixin in Foundation

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I found a solution on how to resize column

```
.col5-unit {
    @include grid-column(2.4); // (12/5 = 2.4)
}
```

However, I'm getting this error

```
[16:17:17] Starting 'styles'...
[16:17:17] gulp-inject 4 files into index.scss.
[16:17:17] [Sass] Error in plugin 'gulp-sass'
Message:
    no mixin named grid-column
Backtrace:
    src/app/main/main.scss:110
Details:
    fileName: /home/ubuntu/testapp/src/app/main/main.scss
    lineNumber: 110
[16:17:17] Finished 'styles' after 35 ms
```

I saw grid-column in the file grid.scss but I'm not sure where to properly put my scss code.

Comment: Show us the file structure and `gulpfile.js`.

Comment: I got mixed up with my answer earlier. All I did was remove .col5-unit css class from main.scss and moved it to another scss file. I was really shocked why it wasn't working when it was in main.scss file

Comment: So let's post the solution as an answer here and accept it - it could helo to someone else in the future, that's the point of this site :-)

Comment: @Akarienta I just posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

As @akarienta's request, here is how I got it working. Without the inclusion of this import code, it won't get fixed.

```
@import "bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/tabs";
```

I added that line to my own _settings.scss

then I put the code below to another scss file. It should have worked in main.scss but wondering why I didn't. I'll have to retest. Anyways, everything is working great

```
.col5-unit {
    @include grid-column(2.4); // (12/5 = 2.4)
}
```